# Get color of highlighted menu item

Tags: c++, qt

How can I get default color of a [highlighted menu item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VdskO.png) in qt?
I want to add a multiline menu item such as [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z6PvY.png). So I created a custom class inherited from QWidgetAction. I want to emulate native look&feel for this menu item. When the widget is under mouse, I need to change it's background color to default background of a highlighted menu item.

Comment: Can u elaborate what you are trying? Your Question is not clear to me.

Comment: QPalette::Highlight - A color to indicate a selected item or the current item. By default, the highlight color is Qt::darkBlue...  QPalette pal = ui.menu->palette();  QColor clr = pal.color(QPalette::Highlight); ?

Comment: I have tried this already: QMenu menu; color = menu.palette().color(QPalette::Highlight). It returns a wrong color. It's too dark.

Comment: Have you tried to simply make your widget have a transparent background?

Comment: You can check how it's done in QWindowsStyle. Thats an internal class of qt. Walk through the source and look for `drawControl`

Comment: Some styles do not use the palette, if they make use of native theme engines.